# React Native needs Node.js >= 18. You're currently on version

Tags: node.js, react-native, nvm

I am trying to create a react native project on my Mac. I've tried it before using laravel and it worked, but this time I am having issues with node.js. Not sure why, but I can't find the solution despite going through several articles.. I have an idea that there might be something with alias' created, but I can't remember as it is years ago since I last touched it,

As the image says, then react required node.js v18 or higher, but I am running v.21. The error however says I am running on version 14, which doesn't make sense to me..

[[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3LOA.png)

Answer (score 3):

try to run node --version with out listing through nvm

or try to uninstall nvm and node then download and install latest version of node without nvm and try again

this could be an issue with nvm